# How to paint a texture together with normal and specular maps via stencil?

Tags: texturing

Assume I have a diffuse, normal, specular maps of my textures. I have modeled a creature model. First texture is skin, second is fur. How to paint normal and specular texture via stencil? I can only draw one map in one time and then save it. Is there a way to combine all my maps into one stencil and draw multiple textures for my object at the same time? Baking can take a lot of time from me and I don't want to sculpt all my fur and skin reliefs and then bake it into normal map because I already have these maps

Comment: I do have the same problem. Its 2018 and in my opinion there should be such an option shipped with blender, because it's state of the art and saves a big amount of time. And I don´t want to waste my money, buying things like substance painter or something. If there is not such an option, I will write a script to do this task. But before I begin, I have to know if there is an option because scripting will take a long time. I do not get why there are not even more people asking for this option, because its essential. Projects like Blender are the future, but just if they do have features like th

Comment: I agree...I dont understand why people say blender is an alternative to substance painter